# How can I pass a list of values generated in expl3 as a single value for a key to a macro such as \includepdf?

Tags: expl3, catcodes, key-value, comma-separated-list

This should probably be obvious but it is not. Or not to me right now, anyway.

I want to generate a list of values (e.g. page numbers and empty values) and then pass that list as a value of a key (e.g. `pages`) in the argument of another macro (e.g. `\includepdf`).

I can generate the list of values I want easily using expl3. I can create the list as either a token list or a sequence. (But I can't use a comma-separated list here because I need to allow empty values.)

However, I cannot figure out how to pass this list correctly as the value of a key (`pages`) in the argument of another macro (`\includepdf`). Part of the problem is that I'm not sure how to pass the list with curly brackets around it. (Or, rather, I can do this with brackets with category code 12, but that is not much use here.) And part of it is maybe that I'm just missing the point somewhere.

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_my_fancy_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_fancy_tl { 1 }
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_my_fancy_tl { , 1 }
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \my_includepdf:nn #1 #2
{
  \includepdf[#1]{#2}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_includepdf:nn { Vn }
\tl_set:Nn \l_tempa_tl { pages={\l_my_fancy_tl} }
\my_includepdf:Vn \l_tempa_tl {example-image-a4}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

For completeness, this doesn't work:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   ,
l.68 ...cludepdf:Vn \l_tempa_tl {example-image-a4}

?
```

How should I *think* about how I can fix this?

Comment: `\tl_set:Nx \l_tempa_tl { pages={\l_my_fancy_tl} }`

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I was sure that I'd tried that, but I must have made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not expanding the value of `\l_my_fancy_tl`: change the code to do

```
\tl_set:Nx \l_tempa_tl { pages={\l_my_fancy_tl} }
```

Comment: Maybe I tried it with a sequence and that didn't work and then failed to try it after switching to a token list.